# Managed Property is not getting updated in Primefaces

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am using an ajax box which will fetch the list of object based the string provided in the box as follows:

```
<p:inputText id="zid" placeholder="Search" value="#{resourceListView.wanted}">
                    <p:ajax event="keyup" update=":form:abc"
                        listener="#{resourceListView.SearchResources}" />
                </p:inputText>
```

SearchResources will fetch the objects based on the value of input box as follows:

```
public void SearchResources(String wanted) {
        this.resources=resourceServiceImpl.listResources(wanted);
    }
```

I was running the query in the DAO which was meant to return the object based on the search. But it didn't return anything. So I sysout the query and the query comes out as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM test.resourcemaster where Resource_ZID like '%javax.faces.event.AjaxBehaviorEvent[source=org.primefaces.component.inputtext.InputText@79d635]%' OR Employee_ID like '%javax.faces.event.AjaxBehaviorEvent[source=org.primefaces.component.inputtext.InputText@79d635]%' OR First_Name like '%javax.faces.event.AjaxBehaviorEvent[source=org.primefaces.component.inputtext.InputText@79d635]%' OR Last_Name like '%javax.faces.event.AjaxBehaviorEvent[source=org.primefaces.component.inputtext.InputText@79d635]%'
```

the query was supposed to be searching on the 'wanted'

Could anyone explain what is the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `SearchResources()` method accepts one parameter, which you don't supply from page. That's why `AjaxBehaviorEvent` is passed to it (`event.toString()`, to be more precise), which is the default if you don't specify parameters in method call.

Try changing the ajax listener to `listener="#{resourceListView.SearchResources(resourceListView.wanted)}"`

Or, simply remove the parameter from the method, and use bean wariable `wanted`

```
public void SearchResources() {
    this.resources = resourceServiceImpl.listResources(this.getWanted());
}
```

Comment: Hey @PredragMaric, it's always nice if you can explain what's going wrong for the OP and then pose your solution with some explanation, rather than just providing a mechanical solution.